# Is it possible to have an #include fail and not abort compilation?

Tags: c++, c

I've got a set of loosely related header libraries and I want to make them work together without being tightly coupled.  One way I thought of doing this is to try including other header files, and if they're found, then I can generate code accordingly.  So perhaps I would have a vector class in vector.hh:

```
#ifndef __VECTOR_HH__
#define __VECTOR_HH__

bunch of vector-y stuff

#endif
```

Then in another file coordinates.hh (let's say it does coordinate conversions):

```
#ifndef __COORDINATES_HH__
#define __COORDINATES_HH__
#include <vector.hh>

class SomeCoordinateType {
#ifdef __VECTOR_HH__
    operator vector() { <convert to vector> }
#endif
}

#endif
```

The idea being the user grabs whatever header files they need.  If they grab the vector.hh header as well as the coordinates.hh, then I'll create the conversion operators for them, if not I don't.  This all hinges on being able to have an #include directive not generate a fatal error if it fails.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Those identifiers with the double underscore are reserved.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that, single underscores it is.

Comment: A single underscore is reserved if it appears as the first character and a capital follows.

Comment: Even this worked, it'd probably be a bad idea because you'd get different behaviors based on `#include` order.

Comment: @Pubby: well heck that doesn't leave much does it?  What do usually use?  Something like VECTOR_H_?

Comment: @gct: `__VECTOR_HH__` is pretty much just as generic as `VECTOR_H` or `VECTOR_HH`.  If you want a non-generic name that's unlikely to collide, you should incorporate your library/module name. (e.g. `GCT_VECTOR_HH`)

Comment: I use `INCLUDED_COMPONENT` for the header of *component*

Comment: Alas, no, the #include thing you are asking about cannot be done.  This is a failure of C that has been much complained about.  There is no "if (exists(vector.h)) #include <vector.h>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C Standard, the compiler must give a diagnostic for the missing header.

Once it has done that, it can continue the compilation and produce an object file it can and wants to do so.  On the other hand, most often, a missing header leads to a major list of other errors (because the header was crucial to the compilation), so an object file is not produced.

The compiler is within its rights not to produce an object file because of the missing header, so you can't portably assume anything other than failure.  And failure is by far the most common result.

(IIRC, at one time — probably ten or more years ago — Sun C compilers generated a message from `#error` but continued with the compilation, sometimes successfully, depending on what the `#error` was protecting.  That's been fixed since.  Not directly the same, but somewhat related.)

Comment: I tried it with a very simple header that defined a const char* string and then a .c file that prints that to stdout if the header-guard is defined, and gcc 4.6.1 generated a fatal error sadly

Comment: That's normal; the compiler is within its rights to do that.  Remember that headers should be usable in any order, too, so you should not demand that `vector.hh` is included before `coordinates.hh` or vice versa; both orders should work equivalently.

Answer (score 7):

One typical way to do this is with a small configuration tool that generates a custom "config.h" (obviously using a name you consider suitable) that just includes the other headers needed for the configuration they choose.

Another possibility is to have the config.h include the other headers conditionally, and have your configuration tool generate a suitable makefile that enables features by defining (or not) the macros that control those inclusions. Typically you'll have a main makefile that defines the actual dependencies, and just generate a small file to include with a line something like:

FEATURES = -DCOORDS -DVECTOR

CFLAGS = $(FEATURES) -O2

...and then include that into your main makefile to get those values defined during compilation, thereby enabling the features that depend on them. Then in your header, you'd have something like:

```
// coordinates.h
#ifdef VECTOR
#include <vector>
#endif

// ...
class coordinate {
   #ifdef VECTOR
       operator vector() { /* ... */ }
   #endif
};
```

I would, however, work hard to avoid having your code crammed full of `#ifdef` everywhere, especially nested to the point that it takes long and careful analysis to figure out what features a class has for any given combination of features being defined or not.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid putting another step between 1) grab headers 2)  compile and enjoy.  I'll probably end up just putting a series of #defines at the top of include files that can be turned on and off once a file has been grabbed to enable/disable features.